# What is the initialize function of this code below?

Tags: javascript, json, initialization, prototype

I have this code from an old website. I want to initialize this function in my custom js file. But I can't understand how to call this function in my custom.js file. Actually, This code performs as like as a scrollable slider which behaves that when I scroll to down than previous & next scroll step will be opacity 0 and current step opacity will be 1.

```
(window.webpackJsonpOdmans = window.webpackJsonpOdmans || []).push([
    [64], {
        433: function(t, e, i) {},
        435: function(t, e, i) {
            var n = {
                "./oddmans-cross-grey.svg": 436,
                "./global-scroll.svg": 437
            };

            function s(t) {
                var e = o(t);
                return i(e)
            }

            function o(t) {
                var e = n[t];
                if (!(e + 1)) {
                    var i = new Error("Cannot find module '" + t + "'");
                    throw i.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", i
                }
                return e
            }
            s.keys = function() {
                return Object.keys(n)
            }, s.resolve = o, t.exports = s, s.id = 435
        },
        436: function(t, e, i) {
            "use strict";
            i.r(e), e.default = {
                id: "icon-oddmans-cross-grey-usage",
                viewBox: "33 -33 88 88",
                url: i.p + "scroll-steps.svg#icon-oddmans-cross-grey",
                toString: function() {
                    return this.url
                }
            }
        },
        437: function(t, e, i) {
            "use strict";
            i.r(e), e.default = {
                id: "icon-global-scroll-usage",
                viewBox: "0 0 14 22",
                url: i.p + "scroll-steps.svg#icon-global-scroll",
                toString: function() {
                    return this.url
                }
            }
        },
        482: function(t, e, i) {
            "use strict";
            i.r(e), i(16), i(11), i(12), i(433);
            var n = i(1),
                s = (i(28), i(34), i(35), i(36), i(5), i(6), i(29), i(3), i(8), i(9), i(10), i(0)),
                o = i(4),
                r = i.n(o),
                a = i(2);

            function l(t) {
                return (l = "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function(t) {
                    return typeof t
                } : function(t) {
                    return t && "function" == typeof Symbol && t.constructor === Symbol && t !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof t
                })(t)
            }

            function h(t) {
                return (h = Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf : function(t) {
                    return t.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(t)
                })(t)
            }

            function u(t, e) {
                return (u = Object.setPrototypeOf || function(t, e) {
                    return t.__proto__ = e, t
                })(t, e)
            }

            function c(t) {
                if (void 0 === t) throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
                return t
            }
            var d = function(t) {
                    function e() {
                        var t, i, n;
                        ! function(t, i) {
                            if (!(t instanceof e)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
                        }(this);
                        for (var s = arguments.length, o = new Array(s), r = 0; r < s; r++) o[r] = arguments[r];
                        return (i = !(n = (t = h(e)).call.apply(t, [this].concat(o))) || "object" !== l(n) && "function" != typeof n ? c(this) : n).setBinds = i.setBinds.bind(c(c(i))), a.f.isTouch && !a.f.deviceTypeByViewport !== a.c ? i.onTouchDetect() : (i.setBinds(), i.initContent()), i
                    }
                    var i;
                    return function(t, e) {
                        if ("function" != typeof e && null !== e) throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");
                        t.prototype = Object.create(e && e.prototype, {
                            constructor: {
                                value: t,
                                writable: !0,
                                configurable: !0
                            }
                        }), e && u(t, e)
                    }(e, s.a), (i = [{
                        key: "setBinds",
                        value: function() {
                            this.showNextStep = this.showNextStep.bind(this), this.initContent = this.initContent.bind(this), this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this), this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this), this.change = this.change.bind(this), this.setHiddens = this.setHiddens.bind(this), this.addListeners = this.addListeners.bind(this), this.goScroll = this.goScroll.bind(this)
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "onTouchDetect",
                        value: function() {
                            this.element.classList.add("scroll-steps--second-style")
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "initContent",
                        value: function() {
                            this.steps = this.refs.steps, this.btn = this.refs.btn, this.cross = this.refs.cross, this.scrollIcon = this.refs.scrollIcon, this.toDown = !0, this.blockEvent = !1, this.duration = 600, this.index = 0, this.height = this.element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
                            for (var t = 0; t < this.steps.length; t++) this.steps[t].style.visibility = "hidden", this.steps[t].style.opacity = 0, this.steps[t].hiddenElements = function(t) {
                                if (Array.isArray(t)) {
                                    for (var e = 0, i = new Array(t.length); e < t.length; e++) i[e] = t[e];
                                    return i
                                }
                            }(e = this.steps[t].querySelectorAll(".hidden")) || function(t) {
                                if (Symbol.iterator in Object(t) || "[object Arguments]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(t)) return Array.from(t)
                            }(e) || function() {
                                throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance")
                            }(), this.steps[t].header = this.steps[t].querySelector(".scroll-steps__title");
                            var e;
                            this.setIndex(), this.currentStep.style.visibility = "", this.currentStep.style.opacity = 1, this.setHiddens(this.currentStep, "remove"), this.addListeners()
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "addListeners",
                        value: function() {
                            var t = this;
                            this.btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                                t.toDown = !0, t.goScroll(t.height)
                            }), document.body.addEventListener("wheel", this.onScroll)
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "goScroll",
                        value: function(t) {
                            r()({
                                targets: "body, html",
                                duration: 500,
                                scrollTop: t,
                                easing: "easeInOutQuart"
                            })
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "setHiddens",
                        value: function(t, e) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < t.hiddenElements.length; i++) t.hiddenElements[i].classList[e]("hidden")
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "onScroll",
                        value: function(t) {
                            this.blockEvent && t.preventDefault();
                            var e = window.pageYOffset < .6 * this.height;
                            if (!this.blockEvent && e) {
                                var i = t.deltaY;
                                i > 0 && this.nextStep ? (t.preventDefault(), this.toDown = !0, this.change()) : i < 0 && this.previousStep && (t.preventDefault(), this.toDown = !1, window.pageYOffset > 0 && e && this.goScroll(0), this.change())
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "change",
                        value: function() {
                            this.index >= 0 && this.index < this.steps.length && (this.blockEvent = !0, 0 === this.index && (this.scrollIcon.classList.add("hidden"), console.log("hided")), this.setHiddens(this.currentStep, "add"), r()({
                                targets: this.currentStep.header,
                                opacity: 0,
                                translateY: this.toDown ? "-50px" : "50px",
                                duration: .7 * this.duration,
                                easing: "easeInSine"
                            }), r()({
                                targets: this.currentStep,
                                opacity: 0,
                                translateY: [{
                                    value: "-50%",
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: this.toDown ? "-90%" : "-10%",
                                    duration: this.duration
                                }],
                                duration: this.duration,
                                easing: "easeInSine",
                                complete: this.showNextStep
                            }))
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "showNextStep",
                        value: function() {
                            var t = this;
                            this.currentStep.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            var e = this.toDown ? this.nextStep : this.previousStep;
                            e.style.visibility = "", this.toDown ? this.index++ : this.index--, this.setIndex(), 0 === this.index && this.scrollIcon.classList.remove("hidden"), r()({
                                targets: this.cross,
                                rotate: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: this.toDown ? 90 : -90,
                                    duration: .7 * this.duration
                                }],
                                easing: "easeInOutSine"
                            }), r()({
                                targets: e.header,
                                opacity: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: 1,
                                    duration: .7 * this.duration
                                }],
                                translateY: [{
                                    value: this.toDown ? "-50px" : "50px",
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: 0,
                                    duration: .7 * this.duration
                                }],
                                easing: "easeOutSine"
                            }), r()({
                                targets: e,
                                opacity: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: 1,
                                    duration: this.duration
                                }],
                                translateY: [{
                                    value: this.toDown ? "-10%" : "-90%",
                                    duration: 0
                                }, {
                                    value: "-50%",
                                    duration: this.duration
                                }],
                                easing: "easeOutSine",
                                complete: function() {
                                    t.blockEvent = !1, t.setHiddens(e, "remove")
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }, {
                        key: "setIndex",
                        value: function() {
                            this.previousStep = this.steps[this.index - 1] || null, this.currentStep = this.steps[this.index], this.nextStep = this.steps[this.index + 1] || null
                        }
                    }]) && function(t, e) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                            var n = e[i];
                            n.enumerable = n.enumerable || !1, n.configurable = !0, "value" in n && (n.writable = !0), Object.defineProperty(t, n.key, n)
                        }
                    }(e.prototype, i), e
                }(),
                p = i(435);
            p.keys().forEach(p), n.a.getInstance().define("scroll-steps", d)
        }
    },
    [
        [482, 0]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Not sure , but I dont think you can do it because this seems to be a webpack generated file

Comment: Thanks to @brk for your reply.
Actually, sir, I want to make a slider as like as this slider (https://www.deleteagency.com/about). Can you help me with this slider?